# Turning off the touchpad while typing on a Sony Vaio SVE14AE13L?

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio SVE14AE13L at work and I can't turn off the touchpad.  The F1 key has a "disable the touchpad" button on it, but when I try to use it the touchpad continues to operate, I've tried pressing it by itself, and I've tried pressing it in conjunction with the `Fn` key.

When I type it inevitably is touched and my cursor jumps to another location.  It drives me crazy and I don't know what I can do about it.

Comment: you might want to update drivers for your laptop

Comment: I had this same problem with my VAIO.  I went to control panel and then Mouse/Touchpad and there was a check box for click on tap that I just unchecked.  That was Windows 7 though, not sure how similar Windows 8 is compared to that.

Comment: @Josh: That option was most likely provided by the touchpad driver, so if the Win8 driver has it then it'll show up just as it did in Win7.